# Unable to clear combobox in c#.net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, c#-3.0

I'm working on a Windows Form Application. I use two comboBox controls which are filled with data from a SQL SERVER table.

When the form is loaded, cmbCategory is filled.

When one of the values of cmbCategory is selected, cmbSubCategory is filled.

Let me put it this way:

If cmbCategory.SelectedIndex=0, then, cmbSubCategory shows some specific items.
If cmbCategory.SelectedIndex=1, then cmbSubCategory shows other set of specific items.

If a certain item in cmbCategory is selected, and then selection is changed to another item -in the same control, all the items in cmbSubCategory should be erased. In order to get this, I use the statement "cmbSUbCategory.Items.Clear();". However, it doesn't happen. The items in cmbSubCategory never disappear. And if I, alternatedly select different items in cmbCategoryComboBox1, the list of items in cmbSubCategory grows and grows and grows.

Here is my Code
:

```
 private void cmbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cmbSubCategory.Items.Clear();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds =category.CategoryData();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Temp_CategoryTable"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables["Temp_CategoryTable"].Rows[i][1].ToString() == cmbCategory.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                txtCatID.Text = ds.Tables["Temp_CategoryTable"].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            }

        }

        products.categoryID = int.Parse(txtCatID.Text);

        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ds1 = subcat.subCategoryData(products);

            for (int j = 0; j < ds1.Tables["Temp_SubCatTable"].Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                var val = ds1.Tables["Temp_SubCatTable"].Rows[j][1].ToString();
                if (!cmbSubCategory.Items.Contains(val))
                {
                    cmbSubCategory.Items.Add(ds1.Tables["Temp_SubCatTable"].Rows[j][1].ToString());
                }

            }     

    }
```

I don't understand why the sentence

```
cmbSubCategory.Items.Clear();
```

is not working the way I expect it to. Or maybe it just simply soes not work as I think it does.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

subCategoryData() definition is as follows

```
public DataSet subCategoryData(ProductClass product)
 {
            string str = "SELECT * FROM prod_subcategory_table WHERE categoryID="+product.categoryID+"";
            ds = dbcon.subCategoryDataDB(str,product);
            return ds;
}
```

and subCategoryDataDB(str,product) definition as follows:

```
  public DataSet subCategoryDataDB(string sqlQuery,ProductClass pd)
    {
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "Temp_SubCatTable");
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: I think you can check this line `ds1 = subcat.subCategoryData(products);`. What data was loaded, is it possible that even you clear all items this method return all rows back

Comment: Can you post the definition for SubCategoryData() here? Something is fishy in that function!

Comment: @Deepak added definition of what it really fetches from the table.

Comment: I would suggest you to cross check your query once(try to execute it in SQL Server with different possible categoryID values and see if results are coming as expected or not) and also debug and see if `cmbSubCategory.Items.Clear();` is actually working or not! Put a breakpoint over the line and check the **Count** of items in the cmbSubcategory!